# How to remove stuck patio umbrella stand

Tags: metal, patio

I have a patio umbrella that fits into a metal tube that is part of a patio end table. The umbrella pole, when it was inserted, was an extremely tight fit, there was no wiggle room once it was inserted.  Now I want to remove the umbrella but it’s stuck. Can’t seem to figure out best way to remove it without cutting the umbrella pole right at the top of the umbrella holder/tube.

The umbrella pole is some kind of thin metal, and the umbrella holder is a thicker metal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What materials are you working with here?  Wood , metal fiberglass?

Comment: Pouring light(machine,sewing) oil down inside at the joint might help.  Make sure there are no locks, holding both pieces together.  Sometimes just a small ball with a spring that needs to be pushed in.  Bet a couple of muscle jocks a beer to undo it.

Comment: Both umbrella pole and holder are metal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [crip659's comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/267781/how-to-remove-stuck-patio-umbrella-stand/267784#comment547556_267781) for the presence of any sort of locking pins!

You don't say whether the base is metal or plastic. If it's metal, the pole & base may have rusted together.

In either case, squirt some sort of penetrating fluid at the junction where the pole & stand meet. Let it soak in for a while (a while being anywhere from 5 to 30 minutes). Standing on the base (have someone sit on it, whatever is necessary to hold the base down) to give you some leverage, twist & pull up on the pole. If necessary, wear some rubber gloves to give you some better grip.

You may have to repeat applications of penetrating fluid several times. WD-40™ is an often used product for this and should work fine if the base is plastic. If it's metal and there are signs of rust, I'd suggest something a bit stronger - my favorite has become PB Blaster™ - I find it quite effective on the rust & crud encrusted bolts under my car.

If there is some sort of locking mechanism, it may have rusted in place, and the penetrating fluid will help break down the rust enough to release the pin.

---

If the base is metal and you're still struggling after several applications (with soak in time) of penetrating fluid and your muscles are sort from yanking and making no progress, you could try heat. Using a hand-held propane torch, heat the base to cause it to expand while someone else is pulling and twisting on the umbrella pipe.

**NOTES:**

- If there's penetrating fluid in there, it *will* start to smoke as you heat it. That's a good sign that it's getting hot enough to be effective, but do try not to catch it on fire!
- Heat *will* bubble/burn paint, so if the base is painted, either don't use this method or plan on repainting.
- If the base is plastic, *DO NOT* heat it! You'll end up with a ruined base and a lot of toxic smoke.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot.  As you suggested I think it’s rusted together but will apply some heat and some kind of lube and see what happens.

Comment: @Greg, you've been around long enough to know how the system here works. I'm not looking for points, but this does help make things run smoothly...

Comment: This was a beast, the umbrella holder was 1/8” thick metal and initially wasn’t heating it long enough.  So I hit it with a torch for a good 10 min until a small gap formed between umbrella pole and holder, then spent 5 min wiggling it back and forth till it came out.  Took forever but heat plus wd40 did the tricks

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, @Greg! Next time you insert the pole, you may want to consider coating the inserted portion in some anti-seize compound - that may help prevent it from grabbing and/or rusting like that. Heck, some simple grease might do the trick, though if you're in a windy area, that may make it slippery enough that a strong wind could pull it out...